# Global uniqueness of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to see that this differential equation has global uniqueness $x'=x^{1/3}cos(x), x(0)=7$, could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the solution has to stay between $x=3\pi/2$ and $5 \pi/2$, and can't get near the problematical $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, I know that the solution stays between $3\pi/2$ and $5\pi/2$ but, does it implicate global uniqueness?

Comment: In that region the function $x^{1/3} \cos(x)$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Sorry, but now I am not sure that the solution stay between $3\pi/2$ and $5\pi/2$ , why can we say that it is true?             I think that it would be true if there was umiqueness

Comment: You have uniqueness as long as you stay away from $0$.  In order to get out of the interval $[3\pi/2, 5\pi/2]$, you have to hit $3\pi/2$ or $5\pi/2$ at some point.  But $3\pi/2$ and $5\pi/2$ are constant solutions, so that would contradict uniqueness.